# Some doubts in Brownian motion quadratic variation proof

Tags: limits, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

I quote **Schilling, Partzsch (2012)**

> **Theorem** Let $(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion and $(\Pi_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be any sequence of finite partitions of $[0,t]$ satisfying $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\Pi_n|=0$. Then the mean-square limit exists:
> $$\text{var}_2(B;t)=L^2(\mathbb{P})-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_2^{\Pi_n}(B;t)=t\tag{1}$$
> where $S_2^{\Pi}(B;t)=\sum_{t_{j-1}, t_j\in\Pi}|B(t_j)-B(t_{j-1})|^2$ and $\text{var}_2$ is the *quadratic variation* of a Brownian motion.

In the proof of the above theorem, firs it is given that $\Pi=\{t_0=0<t_1<\ldots<t_n\le t\}$ is some partition of $[0,t]$. Then, at a certain point it is shown that:

> $$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}\bigg[(S_2^{\Pi}(B;t)-t)^2\bigg]&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\bigg[\left(B(t_j-t_{j-1})^2-(t_j-t_{j-1})\right)^2\bigg]\\&\color{red}{=}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(t_j-t_{j-1})^2\mathbb{E}\bigg[(B(1)^2-1)^2\bigg]\\&\color{red}{\le}2|\Pi|\sum_{j=1}^{n}(t_{j}-t_{j-1})=2|\Pi|t\underbrace{\rightarrow}_{\color{red}{|\Pi|\to 0}}0\end{align}$$

---

I cannot really understand the three parts in $\color{red}{\text{ red }}$ above.

1. Why $\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}\bigg[\left(B(t_j-t_{j-1})^2-(t_j-t_{j-1})\right)^2\bigg]\color{red}{=}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(t_j-t_{j-1})^2\mathbb{E}\bigg[(B(1)^2-1)^2\bigg]$?;
2. Why $\sum_{j=1}^{n}(t_j-t_{j-1})^2\mathbb{E}\bigg[(B(1)^2-1)^2\bigg]\color{red}{\le}2|\Pi|\sum_{j=1}^{n}(t_{j}-t_{j-1})$?;
3. What does it mean to "take limit as $|\Pi|\to0$"? Isn't $\Pi$ just a partition of $[0,t]$? What does it mean to "make it go to $0$"? Does it mean that partition mesh becomes smaller and smaller?

Comment: out of curiosity, I am reading probability theory by Feller and studying real analysis. If I want to learn about Brownian motions, would you have any tips on what I could do next?

Comment: @Quasar: for application to finance, Shreve - Stochastic Calculus for Finance (I and II). I am now considering the purchase of the more formal Karatzas and Shreve - Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus

Comment: @Quasar I would suggest **Kuo - Introduction to stochastic integration** or **Morters-Peres - Brownian Motion** to begin with. Then, if you want a more advanced viewpoint, **Schilling, Partzsch - Brownian Motion** is really good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\Pi|$, sometimes called the norm of the partition $\pi$, is the largest length of any subinterval in $\Pi$.  That is, if $\Pi = \{t_{0},t_{1},\dots,t_{N}\}$ with $a = t_{0} < t_{1} < \dots < t_{N} = b$, then
\begin{equation*}
|\Pi| = \max_{i} \{t_{i + 1} - t_{i} \, \mid \, i \in \{0,\dots,N-1\}\}
\end{equation*}

The assumption states that $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\Pi_{n}| = 0$ and the key point in the proof is that the error we are interested in is on the order of $|\Pi|$.  Hence if we are in the regime where $|\Pi| \to 0$ (i.e. smaller and smaller $|\Pi|$), then the error vanishes.  Of course, this is exactly what we are assuming about $\{\Pi_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ as $n \to \infty$.

By scaling, $\mathbb{E}[(B(t_{j} - t_{j- 1})^{2} - (t_{j} - t_{j-1}))^{2}] = (t_{j} - t_{j-1})^{2} \mathbb{E}[(B(1)^{2} - 1)^{2}]$.  (This uses the scaling property of Brownian motion: $B(t)$ has the same distribution as $\sqrt{t} B(1)$.)

Finally, $(t_{j} - t_{j-1})^{2} \leq |\Pi| (t_{j} - t_{j-1})$ by definition of $|\Pi|$.  Presumably $\mathbb{E}[(B(1)^{2} - 1)^{2}] \leq 2$ holds.  (This can be expanded into $\mathbb{E}[B(1)^{4} - 2 B(1)^{2} + 1)$ and then Wikipedia should tell you $\mathbb{E}[B(1)^{4}]$.)  The $2$ isn't important.  It's some constant that can't compete with $|\Pi|$ in the limit $n \to \infty$.

Comment: OK, so partition is not necessarily made of subintervals all with the same length (?). After that, since, by scaling invariance, $B_t\sim\sqrt{t}B_1$, we have that **[continue]**

Comment: **[continue]** $$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[(B(t_{j} - t_{j- 1})^{2} - (t_{j} - t_{j-1}))^{2}]&\underbrace{=}_{\text{by $B(t)=\sqrt{t}B(1)$}}\mathbb{E}\left[\left((\sqrt{t_j-t_{j-1}}B(1))^2 - (t_{j} - t_{j-1})\right)^{2}\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\left(t_j-t_{j-1}\right)B(1)^2-(t_j-t_{j-1})\right)^2\right]\\&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\left(t_j-t_{j-1}\right)\left(B(1)^2-1\right)\right)^2\right]\\&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(t_j-t_{j-1}\right)^2\left(B(1)^2-1\right)^2\right]\\&=(t_j-t_{j-1})^2\mathbb{E}\left[\left(B(1)^2-1\right)^2\right]
\end{align}$$ Correct?

Comment: Finally, what do you mean by "the key point in the proof is that the error we are interested in is on the order of $|\Pi|$"? Anyway, thank you a lot for your fantastic explanation :)

Comment: You asked "What does it mean to take limit $|\Pi| \to 0$?"  That paragraph (with "the key point" part) was my attempt at explaining that.  The reference you are using is assuming the reader is accustomed to a certain amount of analysis, where (vague) statements like that can be common.  (Also, the computation above looks good to me.)

Comment: (Partitions don't need to consist of intervals all of the same length.  My guess is Schilling, Partzsch mean partitions where the intervals can have any length.  You could try checking if they define the word "partition" somewhere in the book.  In general, different authors, different definitions.)

Comment: Yeah, they not specify "all intervals have the same length". Thank you a lot. Just one very very last fact: on my reference I have just noticed that $\Pi$ is defined as $\Pi:=\max_{1≤j≤n}(t_j−t_{j−1})$ and not as $\Pi:=\min_{1≤j≤n}(t_j−t_{j−1})$. Are such definitions equivalent?

Comment: You want the max step size to go to zero, so establish a majorant condition for the convergence to zero of the lesser step sizes

Comment: So, correct definition is $\Pi=\max_{\le j\le n}(t_j-t_{j-1})$, right? @NicholasLP

Comment: Precisely $\|\Pi\|=\max_{\le j\le n}(t_j-t_{j-1})$, which is a non euclidean norm. $\Pi=\{t_0,\,t_1,\,\ldots,\,t_n\}$, $0=t_0<t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_n=T$ is a partition of $[0,\,T]$, which step sizes do not have to be the same

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant $||\Pi||$, thank you a lot for your feedback! @NicholasLP

Answer (score 1):

For what regards the $2$, it is a result from computing
$$
\mathbb{E}\bigg[(B(1)^2-1)^2\bigg]=\mathbb{E}\bigg[B(1)^4-2B(1)^2+1\bigg],
$$

where

- $B(1)^2$ is the second moment of a normal r.v. with mean $\mu=0$ and variance $\sigma^2=1$, so that $\mu_2=\mu^2+\sigma^2=0+1=1,$
- $B(1)^2$ is the fourth moment of a normal r.v. with mean $\mu=0$ and variance $\sigma^2=1$, so that $\mu_4=\mu^4+6\mu^2\sigma^2+3\sigma^4=0+0+3.$

Then,

$$
\mathbb{E}\bigg[B(1)^4-2B(1)^2+1\bigg]=3-2+1=2.
$$